# How to use outer join, conditionally on a value in joined table

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to outer join a table that contains multiple matches so that I only get one match based on one of the columns in the joined table. I also need to keep every column in the base table even if there is no match.

For example Table 1:

```
ID   V1          
1    A     
2    B    
3    C    
4    D
```

Table 2:

```
ID        V2          V3      
1         4           D    
1         7           C        
2         2           B    
3         4           A
```

I'd want join table 2 onto table 1 using only 1 row per ID, the maximum of Value 2 deciding which one to use.

Example Output:

```
ID        V1           V2          V3       
1         A            7           C     
2         B            2           B    
3         C            4           A   
4         D           NULL       NULL
```

Apologies for not knowing how to create a proper table

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: I answer a very similar yestarday using mysql. But instead of `JOIN` you use `LEFT JOIN` If you have sql server or postgres you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: I'm using SQL server